# Slicing dataframe into new dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have to slice my dataframe into new dataframes, grouped by the destination (I'm using pandas).

This is my dataframe called `data`:

```
Flight N .    DEP.     ARR.     Company
_________________________________________________
1             JFK      GTW      British Airways
2             JFK      LDN      British Airways
3             JFK      GNR      British Airways
4             JFK      CDG      Air France
5             JFK      DXB      Emirates
3             JFK      CDG      Lufthansa
7             JFK      DXB      Emirates
8             JFK      DXB      Emirates
9             JFK      LDN      British Airways
10            JFK      GNR      LATAM Airways
```

I would create new Dataframe gruoped by the destiantion, so in this way:

dataframe_DXB

```
5             JFK      DXB      Emirates
7             JFK      DXB      Emirates
8             JFK      DXB      Emirates
```

dataframe_CDG

```
4             JFK      CDG      Air France
3             JFK      CDG      Lufthansa
```

and so on..

The problem, is that I am able to slice by writing each single destination, but I would create a loop to automate the process.
And after that I would be able to recall each single dataframe writing dataframe_+destination

Comment: `data.groupby('ARR.')`. But generally you do the split as the first part of ***split-apply-combine***. See the [pandas tutorial on grouping and split-apply-combine](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html#grouping). And tell us what step comes next after you split your dataframe.

Comment: When you say "writing", do you mean you want to save each dataframe separately?

Comment: yes, i would like to to that @gmds

Comment: @smci sorry but I didn't find what I am looking for

Comment: @DarioScalabrin To clarify further: do you mean you want to save *to disk* (as a `.csv`, for example), or just in a separate variable?

Comment: just store @gmds

Comment: @DarioScalabrin see my answer please

Comment: `data.groupby('ARR.')` **is** the solution you're looking for. It slices the dataframe into groups according to the column you specify, here `ARR.`. Tell us what you want to do next: do some computation on each group's data, save it, or what? i.el what comes next in your ***split-apply-combine***?

Comment: I would create a dataframe for each singele destination (ARR.) and store it @smci

Comment: @DarioScalabrin: I keep telling you that almost noone ever needs to do just assign separate dataframes and stop there. In a typical flow you do `data.groupby('ARR.')...` then pipe it into some other command `.sum/max/mean/apply/aggregate/transform...`  Please look through some split-apply-combine examples. Again, tell us what's the next step in your computation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this to filter your dataframe accroding to destinations, it's not using group by but should do the work.

```py
dataframe = {} # empty dataframe dictionary
destination = [] # list of destination
for dest in destination:
    dataframe[dest] = data[data['ARR.'] == dest]
```

This code will store your dataframes in `dataframe` dictionary and can access it using keys, example: `dataframe['DXB']`

Comment: You're missing a `data['']` around `ARR.`

Comment: No, I mean you need to do `data[data['ARR.'] == dest]`...what you're doing now won't work at all. Also, you haven't defined `dataframe`.

Comment: and how can I recall each single dataframe? @bhansa

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into pandas groupby
https://www.shanelynn.ie/summarising-aggregation-and-grouping-data-in-python-pandas/

However in order to acess the grouped dataframes you still need too  loop

Regarding your wish to access a dataframe by dataframe_+destination
just write the dataframe into a dictionary:

**Snippet:**

```
dic={}
grouped_df = data.groupby('ARR')

for dest,df in grouped_df:
 dic[dest] = df
```

Comment: Can you help me more? i dont undertsand what means grouped_df

Comment: grouped_df is just my variable name for data.groupby('ARR') - see edited code snippet

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *write to file*, this will work:

```
for destination, sub_df in data.groupby('ARR')
    with open(f'dataframe_{destination}.csv') as f:
        sub_df.to_csv(f)
```

If you just want the groups in a single variable, like a `dict`:

```
df_by_destination = {destination: sub_df for destination, sub_df in data.groupby('ARR')}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work too.

```
dict_of_dfs = {}
for n, g in df.groupby(df['ARR']):
    dict_of_dfs[n] = g
```